# Retrieve record from two Django models in single template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to retrieve the records from two Django models. The retrieval should be like all records from first model and then records from second models based on the username of first models's username.

Models are:

```
class Nodes(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default=1)
    node_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    node_mob = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    node_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='nodes_pics/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class DocchainUser(models.Model):
    docchainuser = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64,unique=True)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

Views are:

```
def universityUsers(request):
    queryset = Nodes.objects.all()
    context = {
        'user_list': queryset,
    }
    return render(request,'universityUsers.html',context)
```

Templates:

```
{% for p in user_list %}
       <tr>
           <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
           <td>{{ p.node_name }}</td>
           <td>{{ p.user.email }}</td>
           <td>{{ p.node_mob }}</td>
           <td> ADDRESS FROM DOCCHAINUSER MODEL </td>
       </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to retrieve the `address` from DocchainUser model based on the username from Nodes model.

**Example:** `test` username exists in both the models. I am supposed to retrieve the record from both the models for test user. And same for all the other users.

How it can be done? I'm stuck here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to give `related_names` to relational fields.  let's say:

```
docchainuser = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name="doc_user" on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

now retrive all data of users and their addresses:

```
result=[]

    for node in Node.objects.all():  

       result.append({"node_name":node.node_name,"email":node.user.email,"address":node.user.doc_user.address})
```

***result contains all data now. you can iterate over according to your req.***